# probability of sequence of integers

Tags: probability, permutations

Suppose you have numbers from 1 to 10. You can choose four of them but the contiguous numbers should have an absolute difference greater than 1. For example, you can choose
$$ 1-3-6-10$$
$$ 4-2-5-1$$
but you cannot choose
$$ 1-2-4-8$$
$$ 4-1-3-2$$
What is the probability that you choose an admissible sequence?

I could not solve it mathematically so I wrote a short code in R

`require(gtools)
x=permutations(10 ,4)
y = abs(apply(x,1,diff))
cf = function(x){
  is.element(1,x)
}
z=apply(y,2,cf)
x[z==F,]
sum(z==F)/(dim(x)[1])`

If I am not mistaken, you can choose an admissible sequence with $0.4861111$ probability. Can you show it mathematically?

Comment: Define "admissible sequence"? Also can there be repeats? Another thing, is it probability of getting an admissible one out of the valid sequences or all possible combinations?

Comment: I have already defined admissible sequence: the contiguous numbers should have an absolute difference greater than 1. No there cannot be repeats.

Comment: Is this right? https://ideone.com/RZGSTG

Comment: neticin-- please see what I added to my answer below, which ends up agreeing with your program's result for the count/probability when repetitions are not allowed in the acceptable strings. Nice problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach to the count: Form the $10 \times 10$ transition matrix $M$ where $m_{i,j}=0$ when $|i-j|<2$, and otherwise $m_{i,j}=1.$ Then the matrix $N=M^3$ has its $(i,j)$ entry as the count of the number of allowable strings of length 4 which begin with $i$ and end with $j$. (This assumes as in Ross' answer above that repetitions are allowed, e.g. the string 2-4-2-5 is OK).

So the sum of all the elements of $M^3$ gives the total number of allowable strings of length 4. To extract the sum one can pre and postmultiply by a row, respectively column, matrix of all 1's. This gives the grand total of 3754 in agreement with Ross' answer.

I've tried to modify this method to count the number of strings in which repetitions are not allowed. That so far eludes me, though I have some ideas.

**EDIT:** I found a way to do the count with repetitions not allowed. We start with the number $3754$ which counts with repetitions allowed and subtract from this the possible cases which have repetitions. There are four types of repetitions. The easiest to count is the form $(a,x,y,a)$ which is obtained by adding up the diagonal elements of $M^3$. (Since $a$ occurs on either end, and the transition matrix bars any transitions to adjacent elements, this count is OK). There are then $336$ strings of type $a,x,y,a$.

The other types of repetition naturally group into three types: a type $(a,x,a,y),$ another type $(x,a,y,a)$ with the same count as $(a,x,a,y)$ by symmetry, and the overlap of these two types which is $(a,b,a,b)$ whose count must be added back in since it got double counted. For the type $(a,x,a,y)$ we form the row matrix of the diagonal elements of $M^2$ and multiply that by $M$, and sum the ten entries, giving $520$ repeats of type $(a,x,a,y).$ Then there's another $520$ of type $(x,a,y,a)$ as noted by symmetry. Finally the number of double counted strings $(a,b,a,b)$ is just the sum of the elements of $M$ which is $72.$

So the calculation is 
$$3754-336-520-520+72=2450.$$
That is, the total number of allowable strings, in the sense of all adjacent terms at least at distance $2$ apart, *and no repeated entries*, is exactly $2450.$ If one uses the sample space of all strings of length four without repeats, i.e $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7,$ one obtains for the probability the number
$$p=\frac{2450}{5040}=\frac{35}{72}=0.486111\cdots,$$
which matches the answer obtained by the OP's program.

Answer (score 3):

I did it in excel.  The entries are the number of acceptable strings of length 1 through 4 ending in the number on the left.  $$\begin {array} {c c c c c c}1&1&8&57&413\\2&1&7&50&362\\3&1&7&51&368\\4&1&7&51&367\\5&1&7&51&367\\6&1&7&51&367\\7&1&7&51&367\\8&1&7&51&368\\9&1&7&50&362\\10&1&8&57&413\\&&&&3754\end {array}$$  The total is $3754$ out of $10000$ for a chance of $0.3754$

Comment: Are these values for interpreting as allowable strings such as $1,4,7,4$ or $1,8,1,5$ which have some values repeated? [It seems so since you divide by $10^4$ rather than $10\cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$ in gettting the probability.] In one comment it looks like OP wants no repeats.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming repetition was allowed.  I was prompted by the fact that the choices were not ordered.

Comment: For counts of acceptable strings of length 2 ending with 1 through 10 respectively, I got [7,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7]. For example if length 2 ends with 1 it can be any of 41,51,61,71,81,91,101. To end with 2 the count goes down by one, strings being 52,62,72,82,92,102. Then to end with 3 the count goes down again by one, strings 63,73,83,93,103. Basically I don't see the same counts you have for acceptable strings of length 2 ending with the left numbers as in the table. I'd appreciate any explanation, maybe of what is being counted. Thanks.

Comment: What about $31$? That is the eighth ending with $1$. For all the middle numbers there are three predecessors excluded, so $7$ strings

Comment: Yes I see, thought for some reason absolute difference was to be 3 or more (my bad!). (and +1)

Comment: thanks for the ideas, in fact I wanted to find a solution without repeats